# Is it possible to extract locals and their values from a stack trace in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

I'm investigating a crash in my Ruby application. The stack trace in my log isn't enough information, and I cannot reproduce the error. When an unhandled exception occurs, I need to log the values of the locals in the frame where the exception occurred.

Is there any way to do that in Ruby?

Comment: Your not being able to reproduce the error and your implication that you have access to (i.e., can reproduce) the stack trace seems contradictory.

Comment: @sawa I got the stack trace from the server log. I am unable to reproduce the error because it's not happening, and as far as I can tell it **can't** happen. I have absolutely no idea how the error occurred. When/if the error occurs in production again, I still won't be able to fix it unless I have more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy to do it yourself, but there is a gem [binding_of_caller](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) [(gem)](https://rubygems.org/gems/binding_of_caller/versions/0.7.2) written by banisterfiend that makes it possible.

Comment: I'll take your answer to mean that it can't be done without black magic that has no place in a production environment... I'll just add some print calls to the location where the crash happens and hopefully it'll be enough information the next time it crashes.